# How to make an intent from onComplete of an observer in android?

Tags: android, rx-android

I am trying to redirect to two different activity depending on some logic from the response. But every time i am requesting i am getting Fatal exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.

My code:

```
this.responseConnectionObservable = apiService.getConnections(token);
            this.responseConnectionObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<ConnectionsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ConnectionsResponse connectionsResponse) {

                    if (connectionsResponse.getSuccess()) {
                        Log.d("body", "post submitted to API.");

                        connectionsResponseParent = connectionsResponse;
                        store.put("token", connectionsResponse.getSecurityResponse().getToken());

                    }
                }


                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                        if (!connectionsResponseParent.getPayload().getPersonList().isEmpty() || !connectionsResponseParent.getPayload().getCompanyList().isEmpty()) {

                            for (PartyListResponse party : connectionsResponseParent.getPayload().getPersonList()) {
                                accounts.add(new Account(party.getId(), party.getUrl(), party.getName(), party.getShareType()));
                            }

                            for (PartyListResponse party : connectionsResponseParent.getPayload().getCompanyList()) {
                                accounts.add(new Account(party.getId(), party.getUrl(), party.getName(), party.getShareType()));
                            }

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SwitchAccountActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("mDataSet", accounts);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                            } else {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateEntityActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                            }


                }

                });
```

What am i doing wrong? I am new to RX and don't how to switch between threads if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

well, it's a little difficulty to tell what's wrong since this exception is thrown when the request is made on a inappropriate state. tell more details about it

Comment: what else do you wanna know??